# QField Project error

Tags: qgis, qfield, qfieldsync

I get this error message when I try to package my QGIS project for GField.

> ERROR     Project QField does not support projects with configured home
> path. Please change this configuration in "File -> Project settings"
> first.

I have tried changing file set up but I cant seem to get anywhere with it.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have a project home path in your QGis project settings. I believe this should be empty

[image]